# create directory in Python

Tags: python

I have python script in which argparse is used to parse the arguments to the script.For instance, the script takes the following arguments:

```
 testscript.py -s sty -m mod -p project
```

when the script is executed, it should create a directory with the name "project". i.e. create a directory with the string name passed to the argument -p. Could anyone help to do this?

Thanks everyone!! i came up with the solution:

```
 path = chap_name

 if not os.path.exists(path):
     os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: Have a look at the argparse-module. Tons of documentation about that over at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#module-argparse). That together with the [OS-module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#module-os) does everything that you need. Get back here when you have some code to share and a specific problem:-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code is self explanatory

```
import os
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p")
args = parser.parse_args()

directory = args.p
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

Comment: thanq!! I got a similar solution